# knowledge sharing discussion forum on company intranet / network drive

Tags: forum, intranet, network-drive, messageboard

I am investigating the feasibility of setting up a discussion forum / message board in my company to enable knowledge sharing etc.

What are the steps involved in implementing such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps will depend on what technology you already have in place and what kind of shop you are. If you have SharePoint (WSS 3.0 or MOSS 2007), then you already have blog, wiki and discussion group functionality built in. Not the best in the world, but it's there.

A shop that uses more open source tools is less likely to find SharePoint compelling. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend a Wiki - we've used Mindtouch internally for a number of years and have also posted all of our documentation externally on a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (or maybe in addition to) a discussion forum, I would recommend a wiki server. This way you can have different howtos, lists, documentation, etc available and the important things will tend to stay up to date. We have one in our department and it is quite useful (if only people would [log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381169/how-to-encourage-non-anonymous-editing-on-a-wiki) when editing...).

I was not involved in setting it up, so I cannot give any details on that, but it is based on [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).